# jQuery - Check if multiple child inputs have a value

Tags: jquery

Given this div:

```
<div id="addActor1">
    <select type="select" id="ddlSelectActor1" class="selectActor">

    </select><br />
    <br />
    <p class="newActor">
        <label id="lblAddActor1FirstName" for="txtAddActor1FirstName">First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="txtAddActor1FirstName" size="20" />
        <label id="lblAddActor1LastName" for="txtAddActor1LastName">Last Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="txtAddActor1LastName" size="20" />
    </p>
</div>
```

When a particular option in the select (which is populated in js file) is selected, I need to check if either of the inputs has anything entered in them.

I've tried the following and similar, but can't quite figure it out:

```
$('#addActorsDialog select.selectActor').each(function() {
    var empty = true;

    // This gives me js error in console: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: p input:nth-child(2)]"
    console.log('p html: ' + $(this).parent().find('p input:nth-child(2)]').text());

    if ($(this).val() !== '0' ||
            ($(this).val() === 'a'
                // || [if textboxes are empty]
                )
            ) { empty = false; }
    //...
});
```

How do I check whether either input has a value here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `]`

`find('p input:nth-child(2)' )`

and to check whether either input has a value here you can do:

```
var emptyInputs = $(this).parent().find('p input[type="text"][value!=""]');

if(emptyInputs.length > 0) {
   empty = false;
} else {
   empty = true;
}
```

OR

```
var emptyInputs = $(this).parent().find('p input[type="text"]').filter(function() {
                       return $.trim( this.value ).length > 0;
                  });
```

Comment: This works as needed, thanks. (Totally missed the bracket there!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log('p html: ' + $(this).parent().find('p input:nth-child(2)')[0].text());
```

This will give you the text value of the first element in the list returned by `find`.